# Website form doesn't work when user clicks google ads link

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

We cannot seem to figure out our problem with our form on our website. It works 100% correctly if someone goes directly to the website URL. We pay for Google Ads to direct people to our website. If someone clicks a paid Google Adword and go to our website - when they fill out the form the submit button does not work. We then receive about 30+ emails with the same request.

I have no idea how to address this problem. I have been searching the web but can't find similar problems.

We have tested the form by going directly to the website in Chrome, IE, Firefox, and Safari. These all work fine.

When someone goes through Google ads - NONE of these browsers work. Normally after the form is filled out and submitted, a pop up appears saying "Thanks for submitting...". When going through Google Ads the pop up does not appear and the form doesn't tell the user that it has been submitted and we get many duplicate requests emailed to us.

Any thoughts here? It sounds weird, but we have tested this thoroughly and these are the results we get.

We are using PHP & HTML.

Comment: Do you want to add the code to your question? It's quite hard to debug otherwise.

Comment: Any errors? Particularly JavaScript?

Comment: view source, what's the action when they came via google, doing something like using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google ads usually adds GET parameters to your URL, maybe this is affecting your form.

For example if your form is located at

```
http://www.mydomain.com/page.php?id=123
```

Google ads may actually make a request for

```
http://www.mydomain.com/page.php?id=123&gclid=DPDCaYGxzrMCFcVY3godsiMAoA
```

More information from Google about why/when these query strings are added

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCampaigns